# mocking an instance method of inner object in python 3.4

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I have a class in my code that makes use of a third party library. I would like to mock the instance method of the object that I obtain by calling an instance method of the library class. I am not clear on how to mock the instance method of this inner object. Following is my code:

My class:

```
from a import A

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = A()

    def do_something(self):
        b = self.obj.get_inner_object()
        result = b.do_inner()
        return result
```

Here is my test class:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from unittest.mock import patch 
from a import A
class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass()

    @patch.object(A,'get_inner_object')
    def test_do_something(self, mock_get_inner_object):
        test_res = self.my_class.do_something()
```

As you can see above, I would like to mock away 2 methods of my library - get_inner_object() and do_inner() which is the instance method of the object returned by get_inner_object(). I was able to mock get_inner_object(), but I am not clear on how to mock the do_inner() method. Please clarify. Here's the help I am following: https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python

Comment: If you mock out `get_inner_object` it will already return a mock on which you can call `do_inner`.

Comment: sure, but then how does 'MyClass' know about this mock object since I am not passing it to 'MyClass'?

Comment: What do you mean *"know about it"*?! It doesn't *"know"* anything, it just makes the calls, or throws an error if it can't, whether it's a mock or not. From your example, it looks like you should be mocking `A` entirely, as there's no way to inject it otherwise.

Comment: @RakeshK: `MyClass` accesses `A` directly, which has been patched. Why would you need to pass anything to `MyClass`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it, the issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mock out all of `A`:

```
@patch('a.A')
def test_do_something(self, mock_A):
    mock_b = mock_A.return_value.get_inner_object.return_value
    mock_b.do_inner.return_value = 'mocked return value'

    test_res = self.my_class.do_something()

    self.assertEqual(test_res, 'mocked return value')
```

After all, you are testing `MyClass` here, not `A`.

Either way, wether you use `@patch.object(A, 'get_inner_object')` or patch all of `A`, the `self.obj.get_inner_object()` expression *calls* a `Mock` instance, so the `.return_value` attribute is returned at that point. The `do_inner` method is just another chained call on that returned mock here, so you can set what is returned for that method by setting the `.return_value` attribute to something you test for.

To translate that back to your `@patch.object()` situation, `mock_b` is then the `mock_inner_object.return_value` object:

```
@patch.object(A,'get_inner_object')
def test_do_something(self, mock_get_inner_object):
    mock_b = mock_get_inner_object.return_value
    mock_b.do_inner.return_value = 'mocked return value'

    test_res = self.my_class.do_something()

    self.assertEqual(test_res, 'mocked return value')
```

Comment: I followed the above mentioned approach to set the return_value of my do_inner method, but when I run the test, I do not get the value that I set in return_value, instead I get <MagicMock object... > object which I am not able to validate. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: @RakeshK: then your call graph is different still; your code ended up calling a mock object that you didn't set a `.return_value` for. You can check what was called by printing `mock_get_inner_object.mock_calls`.

Comment: @RakeshK: see https://bpaste.net/show/e4663a19302d for an example; there the mocked `A` class is called, then on the `mockA.return_value` mock object, `get_inner_object()` was called, then `do_inner()` was called on *that*. So the full call graph for that last recorded call is reproduced by `mockA.return_value.get_inner_object.return_value.do_inner.return_value`.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by changing 'return_object' to 'return_value'. Not completely sure why this works, but fixed the issue. can you help me understand this?

Comment: @RakeshK: ah! That was a typo on my part. Sorry about that! I did test the approach but in typing up the answer I simply mistyped.

Comment: @RakeshK: There is no `return_object` attribute defined on Mocks, but since these mocks were created without a spec, any attribute will 'exist'.

Comment: that's probably why I was not getting any errors even though the attribute never existed! anyways, thank you very much for the help!